# Amazon S3 Object Replication

Tags: amazon-s3

Folks,
  I may be reading things different, however I've been under the impression that objects and buckets in us-east do NOT get replicated automatically to us-west...  However, reading the documentation, I see 2 conflicting statements:

From http://aws.amazon.com/s3/ :

> Objects stored in a Region never leave the Region unless you transfer
>   them out. For example, objects stored in the EU (Ireland) Region never
>   leave the EU.

However, in [http://docs.aws.amazon.com/](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region) :

> s3.amazonaws.com endpoint — Amazon S3 automatically routes requests to
>   facilities in Northern Virginia or the Pacific Northwest using network
>   maps.

Objects stored in US Standard are replicated across multiple datacenters in the Pacific Northwest and N. Virginia, and if you access S3 with the URL endpoint that is not region specific then requests will be routed to the closest datacenter (based on our geo-ip information).

So, my question is, which is it?  Do objects get automatically copied?  Or do we copy objects manually between regions, then use the s3.amazonaws.com endpoint?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Clarification from AWS Support:

Sorry for the confusion there, that is the case in all regions except US Standard. All objects in US Standard are replicated across data-center facilities in the Pacific Northwest and N. Virginia. I will open a request with our documentation team to have the documentation clarified around that point.

Comment: Plus, you can set up automatic replication for other regions http://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/whats-new/2015/03/amazon-s3-introduces-cross-region-replication/

Answer (score 3):

That page just means that the regionless `s3.amazonaws.com` URL will work for any US region bucket's files. It'll send the user to the correct region's servers even though one isn't specified in the URL.

For non-US regions, you have to use the explicit region URL - trying to use `s3.amazonaws.com` as a URL for a file on Tokyo will just fail.

Comment: So, I was correct.  AWS S3 does NOT replicate objects between regions automatically.  Correct?

Comment: And that only a partial answer.  I understand the difference between regional endpoints.  Question is around automatic replication

Comment: According to all the docs I've seen, there's no replication outside of a region. It replicates within a region only.

Comment: me as well, however, this is what we got back from AWS Support! :   http://pastie.org/8427506

Comment: checkout the answer.  Turns out that US-Standard DOES replicate between East and West Coasts :)

Comment: You should reply to your ticket and encourage them to document this. Heh.