# S3 US Standard region

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

According to this post S3 US-Standard replicates objects in US-Standard to several regions: [Amazon S3 Object Replication](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19571904/amazon-s3-object-replication) However, the most recent documentation says that US Standard is just an alias for the Virginia region. Are S3 objects still replicated across multiple regions in US Standard, and if yes where can I read more about it?

Answer (score 7):

US-Standard is an old naming convention, it was used at the time there was only one US region.
US-Standard has now be renamed US-East-1 to be consistent with other naming schemes.

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/rande.html#s3_region :

> Amazon S3 renamed the US Standard region to the US East (N. Virginia)
>   region to be consistent with AWS regional naming conventions. There is
>   no change to the endpoint and you do not need to make any changes to
>   your application.

Also, consistency model has been modified to align with consistency model provided by other S3 regions.

https://aws.amazon.com/s3/faqs/

> Amazon S3 buckets in all Regions provide read-after-write consistency
>   for PUTS of new objects and eventual consistency for overwrite PUTS
>   and DELETES.

In the old times where us-east was the only region in the US, S3's US Standard used coast-coast  replicate of data, as per
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=497527 (2013)
https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=262345 (2011)

Nothing in the current documentation indicates that these mechanisms are still used today (2016)

Comment: The sample questions for the AWS Developer Associate exam still reference US-STANDARD and the old consistency model for S3, which was initially confusing and now annoying. Boo. https://awstrainingandcertification.s3.amazonaws.com/production/AWS_certified_developer_associate_examsample.pdf It's the 4th question there. Makes me question the usefulness of the rest of that document.